# gcloud command to check if project exists

Tags: gcloud

Is there a command for this? I can do

```
gcloud projects describe my-project
```

...and check for an error. But that's not specific to not-found errors. I thought to check the exit code, and I do see that there are some different error codes:

```
$ gcloud projects describe some-nonexistent-project-foo; echo $?
130
$ gcloud projecx typo typo; echo $?
2
```

...but without any documentation, I don't want to trust that 130 specifically means not found. Could mean any server error for all I know.

So, is there any way to check for existence? Another command?

Ultimately I'm doing this because I want to create a project if it doesn't exist. So if there's another way to do that (again, without ignoring legitimate errors), then I don't care as much about checking for existence.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gcloud projects list` to see all projects. To check for one project, do `gcloud projects list --filter my-project`. For a full list of other possible arguments and commands, see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/list), which is very good.

Comment: This answer will work as long as you don't have thousands of projects. Filtering is done on the client side which means you'll wait quite a few seconds just to tell if a project exists or not.

Comment: You can use `gcloud projects describe PROJECT-ID`.  It will return a zero status if the project exists and is accessible to the currently authenticated user. It will return a non-zero status if the project does not exist or is not accessible.