# gcloud cli cannot create project - The project ID you specified is already in use by another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to set up Terraform for use with GCP and I'm having trouble creating a new project from the gcloud cli: [Terraform Lab](https://github.com/sharbeargle/getting_started_with_gcp/wiki/Set-up-Terraform)

The command I'm using is

```
gcloud projects create testproject
```

The error I get over and over is:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.create) Project creation failed. The project ID you specified is already in use by another project. Please try an alternative ID.
```

Here's what I did so far:

1. I created an "organization" and a user in Cloud Identity
2. Logged into GCP console in the browser with the user I created
3. The user has "Organization Administrator" role
4. Using the Cloud Shell or gcloud configured on my home computer, I am not able to create a new project. I am able to do things like "gcloud projects list" and "gcloud organizations list" successfully in both cases (cloud shell & local gcloud install)
5. I have tried this with different project ID names that are within the format requirements (eg 6-30 chars, lowercase, etc). I can also confirm that the project IDs do not exist.
6. However, I am able to successfully create projects via GCP web console (https://console.cloud.google.com) (using the same IAM account configured in gcloud cli)
7. I have tried "gcloud init" several times making sure I am using the right IAM account, just in case.

Here's the error I get when I try to create a new project from the "gcloud init" command:

```
Enter a Project ID. Note that a Project ID CANNOT be changed later.
Project IDs must be 6-30 characters (lowercase ASCII, digits, or
hyphens) in length and start with a lowercase letter. vincetest
WARNING: Project creation failed: HttpError accessing 
<https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects?alt=json>: 
response: <{'status': '409', 'content-length': '268', 'x-xss
-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 
'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 
'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip',
 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Fri, 28 Sep 2018 18:38:11 GMT', 
 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; 
 charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 409,
    "message": "Requested entity already exists",
    "status": "ALREADY_EXISTS",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
        "resourceName": "projects/vincetest"
      }
    ]
  }
}
>
```

Creating the project from the web page console worked fine.

Comment: The gcloud docs say "Note that you can't reuse the project ID of a deleted project."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Project IDs are unique across all projects. That means if *any* user *ever* had a project with that ID, you cannot use it. `testproject` is pretty common, so it's not surprising it's already taken.

Try a more unique ID. One common technique is to user your organization's name as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Google cloud **collects all projects** in the world which related to GCP(google cloud platform)

> So you should create a project with **a unique ID**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another link with more information about [creating projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects?visit_id=636738391451077484-534395226&rd=1).
With detail on how to do it in the console, gcloud, API, and Python.

Another issue that comes up:  Verify that you are using the right account when invoking the commands:

```
gcloud auth list
```

If you are trying to check the existence of the project by using :

```
gcloud projects describe project-name
```

before you try to create it like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391530/gcloud-command-to-check-if-project-exists). The issue is that if you don't have rights to it you get the same sort of error if it exists or not.

```
User [user@domain.tld] does not have permission to access project [project-name] (or it may not exist): User is not authorized.
```

I even tried to create a new project with the same name as a project in a different unrelated org. The key seems to be to add anything alpha or numeric to make it distinct.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

To set your Cloud Platform project using Cloudshell use: `gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]` replacing [PROJECT_ID] with your project name.

Then your CLI would look like

`> admin_@cloudshell:~/underperformance_notifications (PROJECT_ID)$`

Answer (score -4):

I think I figured it out.

The project ID must be followed by some numbers:

```
gcloud projects create tf-admin-001 --name tf-admin --organization xxxx --set-as-default
```

Geez. It does not specifically say so here:
[gcloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/create)

Comment: This is not correct. The project name simply needs to be unique. Adding some numbers to the end is one technique for trying to select a unique project name. As long as your project name is unique and within the length/character constraints and it doesn't use any reserved words (such as "google") then it will be allowed.